# Why Random Results Coming With SQL Group By Condition?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables `job_report` and `index_jobreport`.

`job_report` table "id" column is "`index_jobreport.jobreport_id`".
`index_jobreport` have `DSR_hashkey` column. We group the `DSR_hashkey` column with the main query.

This time query is getting random rows from time to time.

```
(attached files - 
first_result.png, 
second_result.png,
index_jobreport_have_3907327_and_3907328.png,
job_report_have_3907327_and_3907328.png,
query_result.png(one of time)
```

drive - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zlclWLQ_ZJRUnjsQ18TPn4Mv10k7b63u?usp=sharing

This is my query,

```
SELECT
    data.Id,
    indexJob.DSR_hashkey,
    indexJob.EDI_hashkey,
    indexJob.jobreport_id
FROM
    job_report As data 
    Inner JOIN index_jobreport As indexJob ON data.Id = indexJob.jobreport_id 

WHERE
    data.org_code = 'MAGLOGBOG' 
    AND
    data.GB_Code IN ('DEL','JF5','LAX','MAA','ATL','SZX','DE1') 
    AND
    data.country_code IN ('IN','CN','US') 
    AND
    data.GE_Code IN ('FES','FIS') 

GROUP BY
    indexJob.DSR_hashkey

ORDER BY
    data.Id ASC
```

We need to get always Group by with DSR_hashkey and the need to get its First row. But now My query getting random rows from time to time.

**What would be the best possible options?**

Comment: What "random" rows? Your rows are always returned in `data.Id` order. I'm guessing you're misunderstanding what `GROUP BY` does? (Hint: `GROUP BY` does _not_ actually sort rows into groups: it's used to partition input rows for aggregate functions like `SUM` and `COUNT`, which your query isn't using, so you should not be using `GROUP BY` here.

Comment: It was not returned with data-id order. Some times returned second one "second_result.png"

Comment: I don't see anything out-of-order in `second_result.png` Which element (by its element-index: `0` through `17`) is out-of-order?

Comment: No I mean 2nd one is getting 3907328.It not getting 3907327 to result set

Answer (score 0):

You use `GROUP BY indexJob.DSR_hashkey`. So all rows which contains the same value in  this column are treated as one group, and you receive one row for all this group.

You select four columns: `data.Id, indexJob.DSR_hashkey, indexJob.EDI_hashkey, indexJob.jobreport_id`. All rows in a group contains the same value in 2nd column. But the values in another columns differs. Query must return only one value. And server doesn't know what one value from all possible ones it must return.

So it returns indefinite, randomly got value from all possible ones.

---

You tell that you need "first row". And again - you use `ORDER BY data.Id ASC`. But this column contains a lot of values in a group, and server does not know what value must be used for sorting.. and it uses indefinite value producing undefined sorting.

---

Seach the forum for "select first value in a group [mysql]". There is a lot of methods: subquery, window function in CTE, etc. The version of your server is critical - not all methods can be used on some old server versions.

But you must firstly decide what is the criteria which allows to understand what row in a group is "first".

Comment: I mean this is the results list.index_jobreport table have same DSR_hashkey with meny rows.job_report table "id" column is "index_jobreport.jobreport_id". index_jobreport have DSR_hashkey column.If you see the drive images .you can understand table architecture.

Comment: @gimhanas This may be a feature of the data that the server does not know about. You must create logically correct query.

Answer (score -1):

GROUP BY clause should contain all the columns that are present in the select statement

Comment: _"GROUP BY clause should contain all the columns that are present in the select statement"_ - that's nonsense.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).